# How can I use Directory.GetFiles skipping UnauthorizedAccessException?

Tags: c#, exception, io

When I use System.IO.Directory.GetFiles method in C:\, an error is raised:

```
Access to the path 'c:\System Volume Information' is denied.
```

How can I handle that?

Comment: waqasahmed: That's a good way to get a comment flagged.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393178

Answer (score 0):

It's a hidden system folder and the reason you are getting this error is because your application is running under your local account.