# How to check if a specific file exists in directory or any of its subdirectories

Tags: c#

In C#, how do I check if a specific file exists in a directory or any of its subdirectories?

*System.IO.File.Exists* only seems to accept a single parameter with no  overloads to search subdirectories.

I can do it with LINQ and *System.IO.Directory.GetFiles* using the *SearchOption.AllDirectories* overload, but that seems a bit heavy handed.

```
var MyList = from f in Directory.GetFiles(tempScanStorage, "foo.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
             where System.IO.Path.GetFileName(f).ToUpper().Contains(foo)
             select f;

foreach (var x in MyList)
{
    returnVal = x.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you're looking for a single specific filename, using `*.*` is indeed heavy handed. Try this:

```
var file = Directory.GetFiles(tempScanStorage, foo, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
if (file == null)
{
    // Handle the file not being found
}
else
{
    // The file variable has the *first* occurrence of that filename
}
```

Note that this isn't quite what your current query does - because your current query would find "xbary.txt" if you foo was just `bar`. I don't know whether that's intentional or not.

If you want to know about multiple matches, you shouldn't use `FirstOrDefault()` of course. It's not clear exactly what you're trying to do, which makes it hard to give more concrete advice.

Note that in .NET 4 there's also [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles.aspx) which may or may not perform better for you. I highly doubt that it'll make a difference when you're searching for a specific file (instead of *all* files in the directory and subdirectories) but it's worth at least knowing about. EDIT: As noted in comments, it [can make a difference if you don't have permission to see all the files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393178).

Comment: Yes, I am looking to find a single specific file.   I've updated the '*.*'.  Thanks for the tight solution.

Comment: EnumerateFiles does make a difference if you're scanning directories where you don't have permissions for everything (eg. from the drive level where there's a RecycleBin).

cf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393178 for a solution if you run into that case.

Comment: hi @JonSkeet: I followed your answer, but for me it shows tempScanStorage and foo doesn't exist in the current context.. thanks

Comment: @Rani: Well you can't expect to copy and paste sample code directly into your code without modifying it. In this case `tempScanStorage` and `foo` are available in the question - you need to modify your usage to reflect the directory name and pattern that you want to find...

Comment: @JonSkeet: actually i'm new to .net.. here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33729525/how-to-check-already-file-upload-or-image-in-folder-in-c-sharp/33729566?noredirect=1#comment55228879_33729566

Comment: can you please refer this link, and give some guidelines? thanks.

Comment: @Rani: No, I'm afraid not - you should read this question and answer carefully, and see how it applies to your situation.

Answer (score 9):

The alternative is to write the search function yourself, one of these should work:

```
private bool FileExists(string rootpath, string filename)
{
    if(File.Exists(Path.Combine(rootpath, filename)))
        return true;

    foreach(string subDir in Directory.GetDirectories(rootpath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        if(File.Exists(Path.Combine(subDir, filename)))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

private bool FileExistsRecursive(string rootPath, string filename)
{
    if(File.Exists(Path.Combine(rootPath, filename)))
        return true;

    foreach (string subDir in Directory.GetDirectories(rootPath))
    {
        if(FileExistsRecursive(subDir, filename))
            return true; 
    }

    return false;
}
```

The first method still extracts all of the directory names and would be slower when there are many subdirs but the file is close to the top.

The second is recursive which would be slower in 'worst case' scenarios but faster when there are many nested subdirs but the file is in a top level dir.

Answer (score 1):

To Check for file existing in any specific directory do the following
Note: "UploadedFiles" is name of the folder.

File.Exists(Server.MapPath("UploadedFiles/"))

**Enjoy Coding**

Answer (score 0):

It is a **recursive search** on the filesystem. You have some functional examples in CodeProject:

- [Simple File Search Class (by jabit)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/simplefilesearchclass.aspx)
- [Scan directories using recursion using events (by Jan Schreuder)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ScanDirectory.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This is a recursive search function that will break out as soon as finds the file you've specified. Please note the parameters should be specified as fileName (eg. testdb.bak) and directory (eg. c:\test).

Be aware that this can be quite slow if you do this in a directory with a large quantity of subdirecories and files.

```
private static bool CheckIfFileExists(string fileName, string directory) {            
        var exists = false;
        var fileNameToCheck = Path.Combine(directory, fileName);
        if (Directory.Exists(directory)) {
            //check directory for file
            exists = Directory.GetFiles(directory).Any(x => x.Equals(fileNameToCheck, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

            //check subdirectories for file
            if (!exists) {
                foreach (var dir in Directory.GetDirectories(directory)) {
                    exists = CheckIfFileExists(fileName, dir);                            

                    if (exists) break;
                }
            }
        }
        return exists;
    }
```