# How do i check if a file is within any folder and all its subfolders in C#?

Tags: c#, file, subdirectory

I have this code

```
foreach (syncspec.Attribute attr in attributes)
{
      string fullPath = location + "\\" + attr.link;
      if (File.Exists(fullPath))
}
```

and i am checking a know location and an example fullpath is listed below

```
// fullPath = "C:\\Users\\matt\\Desktop\\shard\\all/file30005"
```

What i want to do is look in the all folder and any subfolders within the all folder...any ideas on how to achieve this

Comment: Similar problem and solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994448/how-to-check-if-a-specific-file-exists-in-directory-or-any-of-its-subdirectories

Answer (score 4):

```
System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(location, attr.link, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Read more on GetFiles via MSDN:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316

Answer (score 1):

Your friend is

```
DirectoryInfo.GetFiles("filename", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

as in this example:

```
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(location);
FileInfo[] results = info.GetFiles(attr.Link, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach(FileInfo fi in results)
    ....
```

See the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143327) for reference

Answer (score 1):

You can either use GetFiles(..) as suggested by the others or use a recursive method like this (fully working solution btw):

```
bool FileExists(string path, string filename)
{
  string fullPath = Path.Combine(path, filename);
  return File.Exists(fullPath) && Directory.GetDirectories(path).All(x => FileExists(x, filename));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First do not use simple concatenation on paths, but use [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx):

```
string parentDirPath = Path.Combine(location , attr.link);
```

And second, for iterating over all sub-directories, can use

[Directory.EnumerateDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383304.aspx)

Example:

```
foreach (var dir in  Directory.EnumerateDirectories(parentDirPath))
{
     //do something here
}
```

Comment: Why do you use System.Environment.NewLine and not Path.Combine(location, attr.link)?

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a bit heavier, but I use a variant of it because it allows you to catch any exceptions while searching and continue.  `GetFiles()` will error out entirely if it encounters a directory that it does not have permissions to traverse.

Check this: [Safe File Enumeration](http://tom-shelton.net/index.php/2010/01/02/using-extension-methods-and-the-win32-api-to-efficiently-enumerate-the-file-system/)