# Check if file exists in a specified directory

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I have an image `"1.png"` inside `"Images"` directory. In css, I am referring image as `"../../styles/ImagesNew/1.png"`, but this folder structure `"styles/ImagesNew"` does not even exists in my solution.
I need to check, if `"1.png"` exists inside `"styles/ImagesNew"` folder, which it does not.

I dont want to do anything with this file. if the file does not exists inside the directory, escape from the if loop.

Just for more info, I am storing "1.png" in a string variable filename and "styles/ImagesNew/1.png" in a string variable foldername.

I searched a lot on internet, but i was unable to find "if a particular file exists inside a specific folder".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a specific file exists in directory or any of its subdirectories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994448/how-to-check-if-a-specific-file-exists-in-directory-or-any-of-its-subdirectories)

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to get the file from virtual path, first convert it to physical path using [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), you can read more about web project paths [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx).

```
if(File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/styles/ImagesNew/FileName.Ext")))
{

}
```

> ASP.NET includes the Web application root operator (~), which you can
>   use when specifying a path in server controls. ASP.NET resolves the ~
>   operator to the root of the current application. You can use the ~
>   operator in conjunction with folders to specify a path that is based
>   on the current root, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx)

Comment: Adil, Yes I am using incorrect reference. I know that. I just want to check, if file exists inside that directory. thats it.

In your solution, how would it check the filename "1.png"

It will be ../../ and not ~

If you can please help me  in finding this particular case.

Comment: if(File.Exists(Server.MapPath("../../FileName.Ext"))), Make sure you get right path, you can check what you get by putting Server.MapPath("../../FileName.Ext") in some variable.

Comment: No. I am getting entire path of my application appended by "styles/ImagesNew/FileName.Ext" as "C:\\UserContextTestingApp\\UseContextApp\\styles\\ImagesNew\\FileName.Ext"

Do I need to explain my question in detail.
I just want to check, if a particular file (filename) exists in particular folder (foldername).