# .NET find file in all folder under a directory

Tags: .net, vb.net, file, directory, find

I believe this is a straight forward question, hope I wont get fumed. 
Writing a code to find the **file named text.txt in C drive**

```
If IO.File.Exists("C:\text.txt") Then

        MessageBox.Show("Found text file")
    Else

        MessageBox.Show("Not Found")
End If
```

**"C:\text.txt"** cannot be found when located in a subfolder.
What syntax should be used for this?

I have overspent my time on finding the solution, hence asking an easy question over here.

Thanks!

Comment: If you've read the documentation for `File.Exists` then you already know the answer.  If you haven't already read the documentation, why haven't you read the documentation?  The Help menu is not in VS for decoration.  If you want help on a type or method then use the Help menu to open the documentation for that type or method.  Only after doing that should you consider other sources of information if you need them.

Comment: This is C# but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994448/how-to-check-if-a-specific-file-exists-in-directory-or-any-of-its-subdirectories

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thank you for reply, I have read File.Exists doc and it seems that to find the file, it has to be pointing to the exact location(subfolder). I'm still a newbie in programming therefore still pretty unsure the best way to find the solution.

Comment: @lc. Hi thanks, I came across that as well, not really understand though.

Comment: My sincere apologies.  I was completely thinking of `Directory.GetFiles` when I made that comment. D'oh!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Directory.GetFiles (String, String, SearchOption)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx) method to returns the names of files (including their paths) that match the specified search pattern in the specified directory, using a value to determine whether to search subdirectories.

For example:

```
If System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\Users\You\Desktop", "file.txt", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length > 0 Then
    MsgBox("Found!")
Else
    MsgBox("Not found!")
End If
```

Comment: Hi, I implemented ur suggestion Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\", "text.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories) it gave an error on "@" expression expected. Any thought on this? Thanks!

Comment: @Tim : Remove the '@', it is only applicable in C# code.

Comment: @VisualVincent  Hi, it appears that the get directory cant get in if statement...."1 dimensional array of string cannot be converted to boolean"... Please enlighten me. Thanks.

Comment: this method returns an array of string containing every result of your search (i.e. C:\Folder\test.txt; C:\Folder2\a\test.txt). Added example to my answer.

Comment: @tezzo Thanks! Apparently I missed out the .Length > 0. Does the > 0 means path exist?

Comment: @Tim : `.Length` returns _how many_ files it has found matching the criteria (files with the name `test.txt`). `.Length > 0` checks if **at least** one file has been found.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
string curFile = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
Console.WriteLine(File.Exists(curFile) ? "File exists." : "File does not exist.");
```

or take a look at this link

[How to check if a file exists in a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385251/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-a-folder)