# Need to resume Try after Catch block

Tags: c#

Coming from the VB6 era, I was able to use the "on error resume next" in a relatively appropriate manner when recursing through directories on my system.  If my "foreach" loop encountered a Permission Denied or Access Denied error, all I had to do was call the "resume next" statement.

In C# however, this does not exist and I appreciate why.  However, it boggles my mind to figure out how this is possible in C#.

I am trying to recurse through the directories on my hard drive and populate a TreeView control.

```
private void PopulateTree(string dir, TreeNode node)
    {
        try
        {
            // get the information of the directory
            DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(dir);

            // loop through each subdirectory
            foreach (DirectoryInfo d in directory.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                // create a new node
                TreeNode t = new TreeNode(d.Name);
                // populate the new node recursively
                PopulateTree(d.FullName, t);
                node.Nodes.Add(t); // add the node to the "master" node
            }

            // lastly, loop through each file in the directory, and add these as nodes
            foreach (FileInfo f in directory.GetFiles())
            {
                // create a new node
                TreeNode t = new TreeNode(f.Name);
                // add it to the "master"
                node.Nodes.Add(t);
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Error Loading Directories", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }

    }
```

The code is expected to work.  However, the very moment it reaches the `"C:\\Documents and Settings"` folder on a Windows 7 machine, the catch block traps the "Access Denied" error (which I expect).  What I would like to do is CONTINUE on with the next folder in series.

So the question is, how can I make this possible in C#?

My research shows a common opinion to use a TRY...CATCH block, but it doesn't show me how to do something so simple as what I am wanting to do above.

NOTE:  I also try modifying the code to check the attributes as follows but it too fails.

```
private void PopulateTree(string dir, TreeNode node)
    {
        try
        {
            // get the information of the directory
            DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(dir);

            if (directory.Attributes == FileAttributes.ReparsePoint || directory.Attributes == FileAttributes.System)
            {
                Console.Write("Access denied to folder.");
            }
            else
            {

                // loop through each subdirectory
                foreach (DirectoryInfo d in directory.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                {
                    // create a new node
                    TreeNode t = new TreeNode(d.Name);
                    // populate the new node recursively
                    PopulateTree(d.FullName, t);
                    node.Nodes.Add(t); // add the node to the "master" node
                }

                // lastly, loop through each file in the directory, and add these as nodes
                foreach (FileInfo f in directory.GetFiles())
                {
                    // create a new node
                    TreeNode t = new TreeNode(f.Name);
                    // add it to the "master"
                    node.Nodes.Add(t);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Error Loading Directories", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Which precisely is the statement that throws?

Comment: Have PopulateTree() return a bool.  Return true only if there wasn't an exception.  And add the node only if it returns true.

Answer (score 7):

Move the try/catch block into the foreach loop, so you have the populating code in the try block. That way, you don't drop out of the loop when an exception is encountered.

```
foreach(var item in col)
{
  try
  {
     //do stuff with item
  }
  catch 
  {
     //yes, this is empty, but in this case it is okay as there is no other way
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I tried that and sinch the "foreach" statement executes first, the inner try block is never reached and therefore it hits the outter catch block.

Answer (score 4):

I think your method of choosing sub-directories is flawed, that's why you get the access exceptions - you have to exclude system directories, so something like this should work:

```
var subDirectories = directory.GetDirectories()
                              .Where(d => (d.Attributes & FileAttributes.ReparsePoint) ==0  
                                     && (d.Attributes & FileAttributes.System) == 0);
foreach (DirectoryInfo d in subDirectories)
{
  //...
}
```

In your version using `directory.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)` you *specifically* ask for system directories to be included - `SearchOption.AllDirectories` will include system directories and reparse points. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513869.aspx):

> The weakness in this approach is that
>   if any one of the subdirectories under
>   the specified root causes a
>   DirectoryNotFoundException or
>   UnauthorizedAccessException, the whole
>   method fails and returns no
>   directories. The same is true when you
>   use the GetFiles method. If you have
>   to handle these exceptions on specific
>   subfolders, you must manually walk the
>   directory tree, as shown in the
>   following examples.

Comment: I believe you are right and this is sort of what I believed. Unfortunately I am new to C# so even learning about LINQ is new too. From your code, I follow you up until the argument "d->" and then (d.Attributes....).  I don't understand the "d->".  This looks somewhat like a pointer in C++ but you have a double arrow.  I also don't see where or how "d" by itself is defined.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply as well as the others.  I believe you are onto the right answer here.  I look forward to your reply.

Comment: I'm looking into LINQ and operator overloading which is where I think I might find the answer to my question.  If I am on the right track, perhaps you can articulate how I am to interpret everything in the Where statement.  I appreciate your help!!!!

Comment: @J D Bradley: The `Where(..)` part is a predicate (a form of a lambda expression commonly used in LINQ that returns a boolean), this filters out all directories from the `GetDirectories()` call that do not pass its condition, in this case the condition is that the directory must not be a reparsepoint and it must not be a marked as System. The end result will be all directories that pass these conditions, so you execute your `foreach` only on those - so you won't get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Try-Catching around the whole thing why not do it just where you need it to be.

```
private void PopulateTree(string dir, TreeNode node)
    {
        // get the information of the directory
        DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
```

`// loop through each subdirectory
    foreach (DirectoryInfo d in directory.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
       try
       {
            // create a new node
            TreeNode t = new TreeNode(d.Name);
            // populate the new node recursively
            PopulateTree(d.FullName, t);
            node.Nodes.Add(t); // add the node to the "master" node
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Error Loading Directories", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
    }

    // lastly, loop through each file in the directory, and add these as nodes
    foreach (FileInfo f in directory.GetFiles())
    {
        // create a new node
        TreeNode t = new TreeNode(f.Name);
        // add it to the "master"
        node.Nodes.Add(t);
    }
}`

Comment: on your example he would need try and catch on both foreach as both have possibility of trying to access a folder with denied permission as well as at the `DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(dir);` as you don't know wether you can or cannot access it.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular instance (the find files case), I have a work around that avoids the resume after exception problem (see below).

The problem is that GetFiles()/GetDirectories() or EnumerateFiles().GetEnumerator() forces evaluation of the Enumerable, and thus causes the exception to be thrown at that point.

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9831340/89584 for a code example.