# C# File Permission Exclusion

Tags: c#, foreach

I was wondering if there is a way to solve the issue I have with this code:

```
DriveInfo[] dDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
foreach(DriveInfo dDrive in dDrives)
{
    try
    {
        string sDrive = dDrive.ToString();
        string[] sSearch = Directory.GetFiles(sDrive, sFile, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach(string sResult in sSearch)
        {
            textBox2.Text = sResult + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

When it comes across a file that isn't accessible because of permissions, it will goto the catch and end. What I need it to do is if it comes across a file it can't access, go back to the try block and continue searching. Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: See also [How can you easily check if access is denied for a file in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265953/how-can-you-easily-check-if-access-is-denied-for-a-file-in-net)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1393178/15667

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**
Removed original answer as incorrect.

See: [UnauthorizedAccessException cannot resolve Directory.GetFiles failure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1393178/15667) for some suggested resolutions to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have should work, though you really should rethink your logic, using exceptions for flow control is plain wrong.

This will work, though not best practice:

```
string sDrive = dDrive.ToString();
try
{
   string[] sSearch = Directory.GetFiles(sDrive, sFile, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
}
catch {}

foreach(string sResult in sSearch)
{
    textBox2.Text = sResult + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Where exactly are you accessing files? I only see a call to list file names (`Directory.GetFiles`), and listing of the file names returned.

Comment: Yes, thanks, what would be the better alternative for using exceptions?

Comment: @Bali - Where exactly are you accessing the files in your code?

Comment: I presumed it was here: string[] sSearch = Directory.GetFiles(sDrive, sFile, SearchOption.AllDirectories);

Comment: @Bali - instead of disposing of the exception, log it to see exactly what is going on.

Comment: The error VS gives me is "Access to the path 'C:\C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-232317210-4223013802-3689919456-1000\ is denied" on the line string[] sSearch = Directory.GetFiles(sDrive, sFile, SearchOption.AllDirectories);

Comment: @Bali - Do you really have a path that starts with `C:\C:\` ?

Comment: Whoops, no, I started typing it and then just copied and pasted over it, must have left the C:\ at the start :), any idea's on how to return to the foreach loop after the exception?

Comment: The first one, just so when the exception is thrown then it can return to the get files line and search again, would there be a way of just continuing if it can't access something or exclude it so it doesn't end up catching on the same one all the time?

Comment: @Bali - You will need a `try{}catch{}` around `Directory.GetFiles`.

Comment: That is whilst it is on the same drive, I don't want it to catch, then go back to the foreach loop and start on the next drive - is this possible? Sorry I know I am wording this pretty badly but hopefully you know what I mean!

Comment: @Oded let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1661/discussion-between-bali-c-and-oded)