# Get Directories with Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, recursion, parallel-processing, linq-to-objects, parallel.foreach

I've got a method that recurses over a directory and builds a Tree:

```
public void RecurseFolders(TreeNode mainNode) {
  DirectoryInfo nodeDir = new DirectoryInfo(mainNode.Tag.ToString());
  try {
    foreach (var dir in nodeDir.GetDirectories()) {
      int index = GetSystemIcon(dir.FullName, treeView1.ImageList, false);
      var subNode = new TreeNode(dir.Name, index, index);
      subNode.Tag = dir.FullName;
      mainNode.Nodes.Add(subNode);
      RecurseFolders(subNode);
    }
  } catch (UnauthorizedAccessException err) {
    Console.WriteLine(err);
  }
}
```

What I'd like to do with this is find a way to write a [Parallel.ForEach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop) out of it, but my LINQ knowledge is too virgin.

Obviously, I can't pass the `TreeNode` into the thread, so I modified the signature to be more generic. This is as far as I got:

```
public string[] RecurseFolders(string dirString) {
  List<string> list = new List<string>();
  DirectoryInfo nodeDir = new DirectoryInfo(dirString);
  Parallel.ForEach(nodeDir.GetDirectories(), dir => {
    // how do I write this?
  });
  return list.ToArray();
}
```

How would I finish it?

**EDIT:**

This is pulling a list of directories and files off of our network storage drive. Getting the information across the network is currently our bottleneck, but it is a good place for me to learn some Parallel Processing techniques.

Comment: Just a note, depending on the filesystem you're doing this against, it's likely not going to speed up and might even slow down your application.

Comment: If you are using Recursion there are chances that you encounter Stack Overflow exception when parsing large sized drives

Comment: @techno: How deep do you think you have to recurse to overflow the stack?

Comment: @Gabe I have tried to create a File Name Fetcher myself using Recursion and after trying to fetch the C: drive i have encountered SO Exception

Comment: @techno: I've managed to recurse thousands of levels deep in C#. You can't have a filesystem that deep.

Comment: @Gabe See what i have done http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166990/system-stackoverflow-exception-while-parsing-through-directory-structure im i doing something incorrect?

Comment: @techno: I couldn't create a directory tree that I can navigate in C# that's more than 122 levels deep, and the code from your question has no problem getting that deep.

Comment: @Gabe The Call Stack will overflow at some point or other.So recursion is not recommended.

Comment: You shouldn't reach enough levels deep to overflow the stack for a normal folder structure. You will get a stack overflow if there are reparse/junction points in an NTFS system that cause infinitely deep folder structures. For example, if you mount your C: drive as a folder within the same C: drive. To test for this scenario, go to Disk Management, R-click C:, "Change drive letters and paths", click Add, "Mount in the following empty NTFS folder" and choose an empty folder in C:. You fix this problem by checking each folder to ensure it is not a reparse point during recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But you already did it!

```
    public string[] RecurseFolders(string dirString) {
      List<string> list = new List<string>();
      DirectoryInfo nodeDir = new DirectoryInfo(dirString);
      Parallel.ForEach(nodeDir.GetDirectories(), dir => {
//Just continue writing here. This is an Action. Google it for more info. But for the purposes of this example you may consider it as method which will be called for each of the items
      });
      return list.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to write the Action that returns string values. When I get the string values, they are going to be all out of order, too. Correct?

Comment: Just remember to check for reparse points, as per my comment on the question.