# Fast directory enumeration

Tags: c#, enumeration

I want to enumerate Directory to get Directories. I know the FastDirectoryEnumerator class available on codeproject but with this I can enumerate files only. I need enumeration through network and with Directory.GetDirectories() execution time is horrible.

Comment: What about parallel ? Check this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271094/get-directories-with-parallel-foreach

Comment: Did you try searching? I/O through .NET over SMB is horribly slow because of excessive permission checking. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724148/is-there-a-faster-way-to-scan-through-a-directory-recursively-in-net, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26321366/fastest-way-to-get-directory-data-in-net

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a faster way to scan through a directory recursively in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724148/is-there-a-faster-way-to-scan-through-a-directory-recursively-in-net)