# Skip system-files/directories in GetFiles()

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have this method to copy all images from my *USB* to a hard-drive, say `C:\`, But it throws exception for not able to access `system-files/directories`.

It works fine if I skip `SearchOption.AllDirectories` parameter, but my main purpose is to *copy all images from USB and its sub-directories*

```
 public void Copy(string sourceDir, string targetDir)
 {
     try
     {
         var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir, "*.jpg",  
                                                  SearchOption.AllDirectories);
         foreach (string srcPath in files)
         {
             File.Copy(srcPath, srcPath.Replace(sourceDir, targetDir), true);
         }
     }
     catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException)
     {
     }
 }
```

How can I skip `system-files/directories`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UnauthorizedAccessException cannot resolve Directory.GetFiles failure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393178/unauthorizedaccessexception-cannot-resolve-directory-getfiles-failure)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might help:  (not tested)

```
foreach (string srcPath in files)
{
    FileAttributes attributes = File.GetAttributes(srcPath);
    bool isSystem = ((attributes & FileAttributes.System) == FileAttributes.System);
    bool isDirectory = ((attributes & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory); 
    if (!isSystem && !isDirectory)
    {
        File.Copy(srcPath, srcPath.Replace(sourceDir, targetDir), true);
    }
}
```

Comment: It will not work, because the exception is thrown on the `Directory.GetFiles`, not on the `File.Copy`. Here is the working [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393178/unauthorizedaccessexception-cannot-resolve-directory-getfiles-failure)

Comment: ah. kinda lame that were stuck using trys for something simple like this.   Thanks for the info!