# After catching an error in a Try Catch, how can I return to the loop and keep searching the C drive?

Tags: c#, try-catch

I'm searching the C Drive for MP3 files using Directory.GetFiles (All Directories) but when it comes to searching the Recycle Bin I get and access error. I use a Try Catch to catch it. What I'm wondering is how to disreguard the error and continue searching the drive. Here's my code...

```
    private void toolStripButtonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialogMain.ShowDialog();
        if(result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (String file in Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialogMain.SelectedPath, "*.mp3", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                {
                    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
                    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(fi.Name);
                    listViewMain.Items.Add(lvi);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [UnauthorizedAccessException cannot resolve Directory.GetFiles failure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393178/unauthorizedaccessexception-cannot-resolve-directory-getfiles-failure)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way how it can be done:

```
IEnumerable<string> GetAllFiles(string path, string pattern)
{
    IEnumerable<string> files = null;
    try
    {
        files = Directory.GetFiles(path, pattern);
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { }

    if (files == null) yield break;
    foreach (var fname in files) yield return fname;

    foreach (var dname in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
    {
        foreach (var fname in GetAllFiles(dname, pattern)) yield return fname;
    }
}
```

and invoke it as

```
var allMP3s = GetAllFiles(@"c:\", "*.mp3" ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

One method of catching any errors enumerating a folder within a drive that maintains the ability to late evaluate the directory contents, is to fire events, then enumerates over the events. This avoids the issue with having a yield return block inside a try and catch block.

Please see example method.

```
public class DirectoryEnumerator
{
    public class FileEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public FileInfo FileInfo { get; }

        public FileEventArgs(FileInfo fileInfo)
        {
            FileInfo = fileInfo;
        }
    }

    public class DirectoryEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public DirectoryInfo DirectoryInfo { get; }

        public DirectoryEventArgs(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
        {
            DirectoryInfo = directoryInfo;
        }
    }

    public class EventEnumerator<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerator<T>
    {
        private readonly Queue<T> _queue = new Queue<T>();
        private readonly ManualResetEvent _event;
        public bool Started { get; set; }

        public EventEnumerator()
        {
            _event = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        }

        public void Action(Action action)
        {
            Task.Run(() => action.Invoke()).ContinueWith(task => { MarkComplete(); });
        }

        public void Callback(T value)
        {
            Started = true;
            lock (_queue)
            {
                _queue.Enqueue(value);
                _event.Set();
            }
        }

        public void MarkComplete()
        {
            Started = false;
            _event.Set();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {

        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            _event.WaitOne();
            var notComplete = IsNotComplete();

            if (notComplete)
            {
                lock (_queue)
                {
                    Current = _queue.Dequeue();
                    if (_queue.Count == 0)
                        _event.Reset();
                }
            }

            return IsNotComplete();
        }

        private bool IsNotComplete()
        {
            return _queue.Count > 0 || Started;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            lock (_queue)
            {
                _queue.Clear();
            }
        }

        public T Current { get; private set; }

        object IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get { return Current; }
        }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            while (this.MoveNext())
            {
                if (Current != null)
                {
                    yield return this.Current;
                }
            }
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }

    public DirectoryEnumerator()
    {

    }

    public event EventHandler OnNewFile;
    private void ProcessFile(FileInfo path)
    {
        OnNewFile?.Invoke(this, new FileEventArgs(path));
    }

    public event EventHandler OnNewDirectory;
    private void ProcessDirectory(DirectoryInfo path)
    {
        OnNewDirectory?.Invoke(this, new DirectoryEventArgs(path));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<FileInfo> GetFiles(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo, bool recurse = true)
    {
        var directoryEnumerator = new DirectoryEnumerator();

        var eventEnumeratingEnumerable = new EventEnumerator<FileInfo>();

        eventEnumeratingEnumerable.Action(() => { directoryEnumerator.Enumerate(directoryInfo, recurse); });

        directoryEnumerator.OnNewFile +=
            (sender, eventHandler) =>
            {
                eventEnumeratingEnumerable.Callback(((FileEventArgs)eventHandler).FileInfo);
            };

        return eventEnumeratingEnumerable;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> GetDirectories(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo, bool recurse = true)
    {
        var directoryEnumerator = new DirectoryEnumerator();

        var eventEnumeratingEnumerable = new EventEnumerator<DirectoryInfo>();

        eventEnumeratingEnumerable.Action(() => { directoryEnumerator.Enumerate(directoryInfo, recurse); });

        directoryEnumerator.OnNewDirectory +=
            (sender, eventHandler) =>
            {
                eventEnumeratingEnumerable.Callback(((DirectoryEventArgs) eventHandler).DirectoryInfo);
            };

        return eventEnumeratingEnumerable;
    }


    public void Enumerate(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo, bool recurse = true)
    {
        Enumerate(directoryInfo, recurse, ProcessFile, ProcessDirectory);
    }

    private void Enumerate(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo, bool recurse, Action<FileInfo> fileAction, Action<DirectoryInfo> directoryAction)
    {
        TryEnumerateFiles(directoryInfo, fileAction);
        TryEnumerateDirectories(directoryInfo, recurse, fileAction, directoryAction);
    }

    private void TryEnumerateDirectories(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo, bool recurse, Action<FileInfo> fileAction, Action<DirectoryInfo> directoryAction)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var subDir in directoryInfo.GetDirectories("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
            {
                if (directoryAction != null)
                {
                    directoryAction(subDir);
                }

                if (recurse)
                {
                    Enumerate(subDir, true, fileAction, directoryAction);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Debug($"Failed to enumerate subdirectories within directory {directoryInfo.FullName}", ex);
        }
    }

    private void TryEnumerateFiles(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo, Action<FileInfo> fileAction)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
            {
                if (fileAction != null)
                {
                    fileAction(file);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Debug($"Failed to enumerate files within directory {directoryInfo.FullName}", ex);
        }
    }

    private static void Examples()
    {
        // Recursive file enumeration
        var files1 = DirectoryEnumerator.GetFiles(new DirectoryInfo("C:\\")).ToList();

        // File enumeration
        var files2 = DirectoryEnumerator.GetFiles(new DirectoryInfo("C:\\"), false).ToList();

        // Recursive directory enumeration
        var directory1 = DirectoryEnumerator.GetDirectories(new DirectoryInfo("C:\\")).ToList();

        // Directory enumeration
        var directory2 = DirectoryEnumerator.GetDirectories(new DirectoryInfo("C:\\"), false).ToList();



        // Event enumeration

        var directoryEnumerator = new DirectoryEnumerator();

        directoryEnumerator.OnNewFile += (sender, file) => {
            // dosomething 
        };

        directoryEnumerator.OnNewDirectory += (sender, file) => {
            // dosomething 
        };

        directoryEnumerator.Enumerate(new DirectoryInfo("C:\\"), false);
    }

}
```