# GetFiles Access Denied Exception

Tags: c#

I am trying to recursively go through a directory and use GetFiles to return a list of all the files in that directory. Here is my code so far:

```
public string[] passFiles(string location)
        {
            string[] files;
            try
            {
                files = Directory.GetFiles(location);
                return files;
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
                // Code here will be hit if access is denied.
                throw;
            }
        }
```

But it still gives me an Access Denied error. When I try to leave the catch part blank, it says that all paths must return something, so that's why I put the `throw` statement. Any ideas as to why this isn't ignoring the error and going on to the next one?

Comment: Where is the recursion here?

Comment: @Steve I imagine he's calling the function recursively rather than the function itself being recursive.

Comment: @JayGould, then how come it's a recursive function at all? A Recursive Function is by definition a function which calls itself

Comment: Well, if that is the case it is a waste of time given the fact that we have a Directory.GetFiles that could walk through the subfolders without explicit recursion code

Comment: Using Directory.GetFiles to read the content of subdirectories will not work if access to some of those subdirectories is denied. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393178/unauthorizedaccessexception-cannot-resolve-directory-getfiles-failure) for other people having the same issue

Comment: @Rahul it's not my code, just trying to explain what I think OP might have meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an exception occurs and you catch the exception, you still need to return a result for the function. Initialize your variable files to contain an empty array and then return it after the try-catch-block, so it is always returned, even when an error occurs.

```
public string[] passFiles(string location)
{
    // Create an empty array that will be returned in case something goes wrong
    string[] files = new string[0];
    try
    {
        files = Directory.GetFiles(location);
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        // Code here will be hit if access is denied.
    }

    return files;
}
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393178/unauthorizedaccessexception-cannot-resolve-directory-getfiles-failure) for a similar question and some useful answers.

Comment: What's the point in returning an empty array? doesn't serve any purpose. Better return null in that case.

Comment: @Rahul See [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969993/is-it-better-to-return-null-or-empty-collection) on a discussion of your opinion.

Comment: Wow. Worked perfectly. Thank you so much! Another small question, now how do I modify this to catch an exception if the file is in use? Would it be something like `catch (IOException)`?

Comment: You can just write `catch ()` to catch any kind of exception.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return something in the case where you catch the exception.

i.e. maybe return null at the end of the method - and remember to check for that in the calling code.